# Save Silverlight webcam image (ImageSource) to Server

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, webcam

This is as far as I've gotten.  What code would I write to save a captured image to the server? Without any dialog prompting for a save location.  Similar to the way Facebook does it.  (I've been unable to find examples online)

```
void CaptureSource_CaptureImageCompleted(object sender, CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    capturedImage.ImageSource = e.Result;
    stopCapture(); // turns off webcam
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that simple.

1. Create a WCF service on the server.
2. Consume it on the silverlight client.
3. Call service method to send an image to the server.
4. Save it on the server with custom logic.

Or, if this is too complicated - follow [this tutorial](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Uploading-multiple-files-with-Silverlight-4.0.aspx). It is rather compact RESTful approach demo.

Answer (score 1):

I did i before,
Firstly
ImageTools is good library not must but  a good library, you may use.
Beside this you shoul check for permission for camera access. Then here is the code,
Hope helps,

/*Capture image part*/

```
     _captureSource.CaptureImageCompleted += ((s, args) =>
        {
            //some other stuffs
            domainServiceObject.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.Clear();

            photo = new PR_PATIENTPHOTO();              
            ImageTools.ExtendedImage eimg=args.Result.ToImage();
            var encoder=new ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder();                                 

            Stream stream= eimg.ToStreamByExtension("png");
            if (stream.Length > 512000)
            {                    
                eimg= ExtendedImage.Resize(eimg, 240, new NearestNeighborResizer());                    
                stream = eimg.ToStreamByExtension("png");
            }
```

/*Reload Image Part*/

//note photo.photo is byte[]

```
        photo = domainServerObject.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.FirstOrDefault();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo.PHOTO, 0, photo.PHOTO.Length))
            {
                ms.Write(photo.PHOTO, 0, photo.PHOTO.Length);
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.SetSource(ms);
                imagePatientPhoto.Source = img;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maxim answered before you, but I will look into this method as well.  I'm using MVC.  Will this be posted the same as a regular HTML file upload?

Comment: Noo, domainServerObject is a Domain Service Class uses WCF ria services. And send image as byte[] in SQL server its a varbinary,if you use Oracle you may user BLOB or LongRaw(not offered).Uploading is also possible but silverlight is a bit restricted for file write access, you may write the file on client machine's IsolatedStorage and upload it,I use RadUploader(Telerik's). So you need a ashx handler for this upload. Handler is the main object for upload process.By handler you may upload a file without writing it to isolated storage. Post your byte array, and catch it :) Use it how you want.

Comment: I know it's a month later, but I did some other work, and came back to your sample code.  It is very helpful, but I have not quite got it yet.  I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392232/silverlight-imagetools-to-convert-webcam-imagesource-to-jpeg-not-working