# Silverlight/ImageTools to Convert Webcam Imagesource to Jpeg not working

Tags: silverlight, image

I have a utility that allows the user to take a camera photo and upload it, in addition to another option to upload a file.  I've got most of it working, except for the part where I have to convert the webcam image to a jpg prior to upload.  The code below has no error but produces invalid image data:

```
void CaptureImageCompleted(object sender, CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
    stopCapture();
    capturedImage.ImageSource = e.Result;

    ImageTools.ExtendedImage eimg = e.Result.ToImage();
    var encoder = new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegEncoder();

    Stream stream = eimg.ToStreamByExtension("jpg");

    //DO THIS LATER
    //if (stream.Length > 512000)
    //{
    //    eimg = ExtendedImage.Resize(eimg, 240, new NearestNeighborResizer());
    //    stream = eimg.ToStreamByExtension("jpg");
    //}

    encoder.Encode(eimg, stream);

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(stream);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    // picture file a class object to be used by uploader
    pictureFile.PictureName = "webcam.jpg";  // name will be changed later
    pictureFile.PictureStream = bytes;


    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("gotDetails_WebCam", "");  // post page, then come back and do upload
}
```

Here is what PictureFile looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class PictureFile
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PictureName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] PictureStream { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong to produce the bytes needed for a jpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good to see that you solved,

here is my running code,
I use png format,there is also file size check.
Maybe it helps s.one else.

dSrvPR is my Domain Service Class instance

photo is an entity object in my EF.

```
_captureSource.CaptureImageCompleted += ((s, args) =>
        {
            if (dSrvPR.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.Count > 0 && photo != null)
            {
                dSrvPR.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.Remove(photo);
            }

            dSrvPR.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.Clear();

            photo = new PR_PATIENTPHOTO();

            ImageTools.ExtendedImage eimg=args.Result.ToImage();
            var encoder=new ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder();                                 

            Stream stream= eimg.ToStreamByExtension("png");
            if (stream.Length > 512000)
            {                    
                eimg= ExtendedImage.Resize(eimg, 240, new NearestNeighborResizer());                    
                stream = eimg.ToStreamByExtension("png");
            }                     
            if (stream.Length <= 512001)
            {
                BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(stream);
                //Read bytes from the BinaryReader and put them into a byte array.
                Byte[] file = binary.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                photo.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                photo.PHOTO = file;
                photo.PHOTODATE = DateTime.Now;
                photo.ISACTIVE = true;
                //some more unrelated fields
                dSrvPR.PR_PATIENTPHOTOs.Add(photo);
                dSrvPR.SubmitChanges();
  //Msg succedded
            }
            else
            {
                Util.alert(...,"file size exceeded! :)";
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciated your addition of the Resizer for large images.  Is NearestNeighborResizer part of ImageTools?

Comment: in ImageTools.Filtering.dll there is a ImageTools.Filtering.NearestNeighborResizer implements IImageResizer .It means you may code your own resizer also. I like NearestNeighborResizer ,Its very successfull. I use this technic in Photoshop also. There are some other methods such as bicubic but I tested this is better. Some webcams have high resolutions so I needed to resize.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  It seems I had some extra code in there (unnecessarily converting stream to bitmap).  Here is what I got working:

```
void CaptureImageCompleted(object sender, CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
    stopCapture();
    capturedImage.ImageSource = e.Result;

    ImageTools.ExtendedImage eimg = e.Result.ToImage();
    var encoder = new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegEncoder();

    Stream stream = eimg.ToStreamByExtension("jpg");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    // picture file a class object to be used by uploader
    pictureFile.PictureName = "webcam.jpg";  // name will be changed later
    pictureFile.PictureStream = bytes;


    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("gotDetails_WebCam", "");  // post page, then come back and do upload
}
```