# Why is it so hard to capture a picture from a webcam and save it on the server in silverlight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

This seems like a simple enough task that would pop up frequently enough to require a rather straight forward framework to implement. But I have been working on this for almost a week now and can't find a solution.

**Task**
The user is on an asp.net page that has a multiview. View1 of this multiview contains a simple form where a user enters a pin. If correct, the user is taken to view2 where a silverlight app will open with the webcam on and a button. Upon the button click the user picture will be saved in a database along with the pin number entered and the user will be redirected to View1.

**What I have done**
I have created the page with a multiview containing view1 and view2.
I have embedded a silverlight application in view2 and have successfully captured the image on a button click and gotten access to the result as a writeable bitmap inside the silverlight app.

**What I can't do**
Right now I plan on converting this image to a byte array that can be saved in a sql database varbinary(max) column. The byte array should represent a compressed jpeg so that the average picture should be ~22 KB in size.

**Suggested approaches that I have tried**
A similar post ([Save Silverlight webcam image (ImageSource) to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899533/save-silverlight-webcam-image-imagesource-to-server)) has a somewhat cookbook solution but I have not been able to implement it. I run into the following problems

1. How to convert the writeable bitmap captured by the silverlight app into a byte array of a reasonable size that represents a jpeg file.
2. Right now the array is of too large a size so that when I send it to a WCF service the transfer fails
3. I need to access some values from the asp.net page in which the silverlight application is hosted (pin number, system.datatime.now etc) to execute a query on a database and then change the view in a multiview in the asp.net page (away from the silverlight app). I can't make progress on making an asp.net page and the silverlight application work in coordination through a WCF service.

I have been working on this for a while am running into a bunch of hurdles at the same time. Is there a much straightforward approach to this task?

Comment: Take WCF out of the picture and POST the bytes to a normal HTTP endpoint in your ASP.NET app. I'd only use WCF if required.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to remove the ranting and to focus on the current problem.

Comment: How do I do it from silverlight?

Comment: Looks like you overcomplicating things. Can you just stream bytes to asp handler from Silverlight and in handler stream them to db?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to create an asp handler from silverlight?

Comment: It's handler on server side. Right click on "Web" project -> add item -> Generic handler. 

In it's code you can read incoming request stream and then write it to database or file. You can use UPDATE .WRITE for MS SQL to stream data into database or use memory stream to store data in memory and write it at once.